# UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int

Tags: android, android-ndk

Although method naming seems correct, IDE throws an error of no implementation.

I've checked spelling in my c++ code.

This error happens when it tries to use native method:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int pl.mike.LinkVideoCore.sysinit(java.lang.String) (tried Java_pl_mike_LinkVideoCore_sysinit and Java_pl_mike_LinkVideoCore_sysinit__Ljava_lang_String_2)
        at pl.mike.LinkVideoCore.sysinit(Native Method)
        at pl.mike.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
```

MainActivity looks like this:

```
linkStream = new LinkVideoCore();
        linkStream.sysinit("192.168.11.123");
```

This is LinkVideoCore:

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("mp3lame");
        System.loadLibrary("linkcardplayer");
        System.loadLibrary("linkcardsdk");
    }

    public native int sysinit(String pIP);
```

This is how I configured Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := mp3lame
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libmp3lame.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := linkcardplayer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/liblinkcardplayer.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := linkcardsdk

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH) 

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/sdk.h

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    sdk-jni-demo.c 

LOCAL_LDLIBS  +=  -Wl,--gc-sections -llog -lz -ldl -ljnigraphics
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := mp3lame linkcardplayer

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
#include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI :=armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-17
APP_STL := c++_static
TARGET_ARCH_ABI :=armeabi-v7a
```

sdk-jni-demo.c:

```
jint  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) Java_pl_mike_LinkVideoCore_sysinit(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jstring jname)
{
    int ret = 0;
    const char * pRemoteIP  = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,jname, NULL);   //
    LOGV("[%s-%d]: \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    SDK_Entry();
    ret = SDK_Connect(pRemoteIP);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env,jname, pRemoteIP);
    return ret;
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pl.mike.xeyepoc"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets{
        main{
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: So where are you triggering the NDK build from? And why do you have all those ABIs in your `abiFilters` list when you're only building your native libraries for armeabi-v7a?

Comment: I have zero to none experience with NDK, so I was just following as much as I could read about it. The entire thing is what I was able to come up with. Can you be more precise? Thank you!

Comment: "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" why? If you're having trouble one of the first things you should try is using up to date tools.